# Переносил сайт с хостинга, на хостинг, вылезла ошибка, как ее убрать и в чем ее причина?

Tags: wordpress, cms, хостинг, домен

Сайт, о котором идет речь j63225gt.beget.tech

Переносил сайт с хостинга, на хостинг, вылезла ошибка, как ее убрать и в чем ее причина ?
Error: Your upload path is not valid or does not exist: /home/y/yrchikpu/picca.com.ua/public_html/wp-content/uploads

Вообщем как я делал перенос с хостинга на хостинг, с заменой старого домена на новый домен. Сначала на первом хостинге сделал архив сайта . На втором хостинге открыл технический домен, открыл базу данных MYSCL . Все пролинковалось . Потом на втором хостинге в папку сайта загрузил архив, разархивировал его, потом WP-config поменял название базы данных и пароль базы данных. Потом экспортировал с первого хостинга базу данных, загрузил на второй хостинг базу данных. Потом через утилиту меняю линки на сайте Search-Replace-DB
github.com/artikus11/Search-Replace-DB ссылка утилиты.
Сайт был перенесен, база данных тоже, то вылезла ссылка с ошибкой, о которой я говорю . Подскажите где вручную прописать в файловой системе путь, чтобы все работало, и не было ошибок, или что я делаю не так ? .Также плагины не обновляются . Скрины загрузил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В каком файле вылезает ошибка?

Comment: Менять надо не только линки, но и пути. Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561/220220

Comment: а директория сама существует физически? Откройте wp-content, есть там директория uploads?

Comment: Если ответ на вопрос был исчерпывающим, пожалуйста, подтвердите его как решенный.

Answer (score 0):

возможно еще это поможет, в базе данных так же надо делать изменения https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/updating-wordpress-mysql-database-after-moving-to-a-new-url/
по этой ссылке подробная инструкция

Comment: По этой ссылке как НЕЛЬЗЯ делать. Как правильно - тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561/220220